# Serve embedded filesystem from root path of URL

Tags: go

Go 1.16 added the new [embed](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/) package. I would like to use this package to embed a directory and serve it over HTTP. Consider the following setup:

```
myproject/
|-- main.go
|-- static/
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- styles.css
|   |-- scripts.js
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed static
var staticFS embed.FS

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFS)))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

With this setup, my expectation is that I can point my browser to `localhost:8080` and have it load `index.html`. What I am observing instead, is that I need to point my browser to `localhost:8080/static` to have it load `index.html`.

How can an embedded filesystem be served from the root path of the URL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When declaring a variable of type [embed.FS](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/#FS), that variable represents a filesystem that already contains a root directory. All resources from the `//go:embed` directive are copied into this root directory of the filesystem. That means that the `staticFS` variable does not refer to the `static` folder that was being embedded directly, but to the root directory that contains the `static` folder. With that in mind, to achieve the desired result of being able to access the `static` folder from `localhost:8080`, Go's [fs.Sub](https://golang.org/pkg/io/fs/#Sub) can be used to pass a filesystem to the server where the `static` folder is the root:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed static
var embeddedFS embed.FS

func main() {
    serverRoot, err := fs.Sub(embeddedFS, "static")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(serverRoot)))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to `fs.Sub` you can declare embedding inside the static directory.

```
package static

//go:embed *.html *.css *.js
var FS embed.FS
```

And then import it.

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "import/path/to/static"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(static.FS)))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The downside of adding embedding into static directory is that `*.go` file may be also added as embedded unless strict file masks are used (e.g. `//go:embed *.html *js` instead of `//go:embed *`).

Edit: Removed additionally proposed `http.StripPrefix` because it does not actually help with issue.

Comment: The first of the two alternatives works beautifully. When I try the second alternative (using http.StripPrefix) though, I only get `index.html` at `localhost:8080/static/static`.

Comment: Oh, you're right! It works the other way around, I confused it with non-existent `http.AddPrefix` :)
Pardon.