# Embeded assets will not load and returns a status code 404

Tags: http, go, embed, assets, gorilla

The code below is a simple http server written in GO. When I run the code, I expect the server to return the embedded assets from the assets folder, but it only returns a list of files. When I try to open one of the files in the folder, I get a status code 404 (page not found). I can't figure out why the assets don't load.

The URLs I'm using are http://localhost:9876/assets to list the files and http://localhost:9876/assets/app.js to try to load the content of a file.

Please help me figure out why the code doesn't run as expected.

```
package main

import (
  "embed"
  "fmt"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

//go:embed assets
var assets embed.FS

func main() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.Handle("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.FS(assets)))

  srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:      r,
    Addr:         fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 9876),
  }

  log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serve embedded filesystem from root path of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248258/serve-embedded-filesystem-from-root-path-of-url)

Comment: Note that `r.Handle("/"..` would work as you expect (but is probably not what you want!); alternatively use `fs.Sub(assets , "assets")`.

Comment: It turns out like this: if I use gorilla mux, the code doesn't run as expected, but if I use net/http it returns the static embedded files. I haven't looked into what causes this when I use gorilla mux.

Comment: Sorry - with gorilla you can use `r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(assets)))` (I usually just use stdlib so the differences are sometimes confusing!).